# How does one create an generalise AttrDict Mixin for a python "dict-style" class?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, attributes, multiple-inheritance

Basically I want to be able to take `class` that *quacks* like a `dict` (eg my example `DICT` below) and add a `MixIn` that allows me to access the `DICT`'s values as attributes... eg

```
print purchase.price # instead of purchase["price"]
```

Background: I have a various different database tables (not just the `DICT` example) that look (& *quack*) like a `dict` (eg. `bsddb`) and I want define (then use) a standard `AttrDictMixIn`.  (And so avoid using a boilerplate cut/paste of code)

```
# First try using a std dict
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__ = self
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

test1=AttrDict()
test1.x="111"
print 1,test1

# Next derive a crude UPPER dict
class DICT(dict): # EXAMPLE ONLY
  def __getitem__(self,key):
    return super(DICT,self).__getitem__(key.upper())

  def __setitem__(self,key,value):
    return super(DICT,self).__setitem__(key.upper(),value)

test2=DICT()
test2["x"]="222"
print 2,test2

# Next define a AttrDict MixIn
class AttrDictMixIn(object):  # This is what I want to work...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__ = self
        return super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

# Apply the MixIn to DICT 
class AttrDICT(DICT,AttrDictMixIn): pass

test3=AttrDICT()
test3.x="333.xxx"
test3["y"]="333.yyy"
print 3,test3,"X is missing"
print 4,"test3.x:",test3.x,"OK"
print 5,"test3['y']:",test3["y"],"OK"
print 6,"test3.y:",test3.y,"DUD"
print 7,"test3['x']:",test3["x"],"DUD"
```

Output:

```
1 {'x': '111'}
2 {'X': '222'}
3 {'Y': '333.yyy'} X is missing
4 test3.x: 333.xxx OK
5 test3['y']: 333.yyy OK
6 test3.y:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 39, in <module>
    print 6,"test3.y:",test3.y,"DUD"
AttributeError: 'AttrDICT' object has no attribute 'y'
```

I suspect I am doing something trivial wrong... Hints welcome.
(And pointers to some reference examples of similar python MixIns may also help)

edit: an explanation of why the line `self.__dict__ = self` breaks multiple inheritance would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean *But it doesn't work*? You want to post a traceback of your error?

Comment: Just added a "X is missing" comment and a traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Implement it like so:

```
class AttrDictMixin(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self[name] = value
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        del self[name]
```

Upon attribute access, setting, or deleting - `__getattr__`, `__setattr__` and `__delattr__` are called accordingly.

Keep in mind mixins should come before the base class in the inheritance:

```
class AttrDict(AttrDictMixin, DICT): pass
```